# Ninject : How Get inherited type instead Base type when inherited type marked by attribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

How do I get the inherited type instead of the base type when the inherited type is marked by attribute?

Can we do it with Ninject or not?  Here's what I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

    // use Method which return properly type
    kernel.Bind<IBase>().ToMethod(context => SOMEMETHOD());

    // should be return DerivedClass 
    BaseClass derived = kernel.Get<BaseClass>();
    BaseClass1 derived1 = kernel.Get<BaseClass1>();

    // The result should be:
    derived.WhoIAm();  //--> "DerivedClass"
    derived1.WhoIAm(); //--> "DerivedClass1"
}

// method which resolve this
static object SOMEMETHOD()
{
    // return derived class wich marked by
    // SomeAttribure where base class that which we use in kernel.Get 
}
```

Base Classes

```
class BaseClass : IBase
{    
    public virtual void WhoIAm()
    {
        Console.Write(this.GetType());
    }   
}

class BaseClass1 : IBase
{    
    public virtual void WhoIAm()
    {
        Console.Write(this.GetType());
    }   
}
```

Inherited Classes. `SomeAttribute` is an attribute that marks the type that should be created

```
[SomeAttribute]
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void WhoIAm()
    {
        Console.Write(this.GetType());
    }
}
```

Other Derived classes inheriting from `BaseClass1`

```
[SomeAttribute]
class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass1
{
    public override void WhoIAm()
    {
        Console.Write(this.GetType());
    }
}    
class SomeAttribute : Attribute {}

interface IBase
{
    void WhoIAm();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the convention extension. Should be straight forward. Something like

```
kernel.Bind(x =>
{
    x.FromThisAssembly()
     .SelectAllClasses()
     .WithAttribute<SomeAttribute>()
     .BindBase();
});
```